# Merge branch in SourceTree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Newbie Question alert !  My requirement is to merge a whole BugFixing branch to the development. On source tree there are two options when you go in to merging . "Merge from Log" and "Merge Fetched" . What's the correct option I should select ? Is merge from log only merge a specific commit ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should prefer the "Merge from fetch", this means that before the merge source tree will fetch the latest code from the remote repository.

By the way sourcetree tree do auto fetch every 10 minutes (can be configured in the preferences screen).

Merge from log will use the latest local commit.

Comment: when you say "latest local commit" is it only that commit (like cherry picking") or all the commits below that commit that haven't been merged before ?

Comment: It should be all the local commits (plural)